# Rails Rendering a Single Partial after Page Load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a partial page in my application named _dashboard.html.erb. Inside of the dashboard, I have a lot of calls to render different partials. One of those is the _calendar.html.erb partial, which makes a call to google calendar and pulls down a list of events. This load takes time and I want to have the _calendar partial load after the rest of the dashboard has loaded. It should be reiterated that I don't want this to be based on a click event and instead when the page loads.

pages_controller.rb

```
# Logged in to shift
def jump
@title = "#{User.find(session[:user_id]).firstname}'s Dashboard"
@tasks = Task.where(:completed => 0)
@questions = Question.where(:answered => 0)


serv = GCal4Ruby::Service.new
serv.authenticate("email","pass")
cal = GCal4Ruby::Calendar.find(serv, {:title => "Skidmore Center for Sex and Gender Relations"})
#@events = GCal4Ruby::Event.find(serv, {'start-min' => Time.now.utc.xmlschema, 'start-max' => 5.days.from_now.utc.xmlschema })
@events = GCal4Ruby::Event.find(serv, {'start-min' => Time.parse("01/01/2011").utc.xmlschema, 'start-max' => Time.parse("06/01/2011").utc.xmlschema, :calendar => cal.id})

end
```

Jump is the page where I have the dashboard partial rendering. Here is the part of /app/views/layouts/_dashboard.html.erb that calls the calendar partial:

```
<div id="main-content">
  <div class="post">
    <h3>calendar</h3>
    <%= render 'layouts/calendar' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And /app/views/layouts/_calendar.html.erb

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <% if event.start_time >= Time.now and event.start_time <= 5.days.from_now %><li><%= event.start_time.to_s(:short) %> <%= event.title %></li><% end %>
<% end %>
```

I think what you should keep in mind here is that, while I understand how AJAX works, I have little to no experience coding it by itself or in Rails. Any help here would be appreciated (And the more dumbed-down and explained the better!)

Thanks

***Update:*** I used the async_partial gem but am now having issues with the partial pulling the events from google calendar. The partial works without the async_partial.

Comment: I've made a basic gem to load partials with ajax. check: https://github.com/apneadiving/AsyncPartial/wiki. If it fits, I'll post it as an answer

Comment: tell me if you need more explanations

Comment: Definitely looks right, I'm going to look into how to apply it. How exactly do I get jquery into my app?

Comment: Side notes, but you should consider two things: 1) use named scopes, and 2) don't post real username/password to stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: :) I should probably fix that and change our password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way to handle this without a gem, which is quite common by the way, is to use some kind of event handler for the page load event. For instance, with jQuery, you can do :

```
// this get executed when jQuery is made available, which means when 
// your document is ready.
$(function () {

    // you replace the actual calendar content with the piece that is 
    // rendered with your partial
    $("#your-calendar-div-id").replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/calendar') %>');

});
```

Comment: $(function () {
 
     $("#calendar").replaceWith('      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      <li>01 Sep 11:30 test<\/li>\n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n      \n');
 
 });

Comment: ^^ That's the HTML output. Any idea how to get rid of all those \n's?

Comment: Every new line in your view is transfered to \n. These are javascript new lines. If you want to get rid of them, remove new lines from your view.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? From what I can see the partial will be loaded at the same time as the javascript is rendered - ie. at the same time as the initial load of the page. There's no AJAX call.

Comment: In the answer, it says to use "some kind of event handler". You can use a button click, ajax call, etc. In this case, it was taken from a file called destroy.js.erb, which handles the destroy action with a JS renderer..

Comment: So is the function example in the answer in a separate file which is loaded by the main page using an AJAX call?

Comment: Yes it is. It's only an example which meant to include the way to insert a partial using javascript. Adapt it as you need.

Comment: OK, but I think your answer could do with editing to include this as without it it's incomplete - unless someone already knows the answer I can't see what about your answer would lead them to it. If they just put the javascript in a `<%= content_for :head %>` it wouldn't work, and neither would it work if a `javascript_include_tag` was used to include the file with the function in it. I know it seems basic but I've seen plenty of people on here not understand the difference between when `.erb` is rendered and when javascript is run.